# pg.query not calling callback function

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I'm using `pg` for node to connect to my Postgres server.

Here is what I'm doing:

```
const Pool = require('pg').Pool;

var config = {
    user: "mouser",
    password: "my password",
    host: "somethingsomething.rds.amazonaws.com",
    port: 5432,
    database: "mydb",
    ssl: true
}

const db = new Pool(config);

console.log("hello world")

let queryString = `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS favoritememes (id serial PRIMARY KEY, image_url varchar(255), date_favorited TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);`
db.query(queryString, function(err, result) {
    console.log("Created table");
    if (err) console.log("error", err);
});
```

Currently, I see "hello world" printed to my console, but it never prints "created table" and I also never see an error.

I know that my credentials are correct because I can connect to the server with SQLWorkbench with those same credentials.

Comment: And was the table created or not on the amazon aws server?

Answer (score 0):

**I think the issue is that you're not waiting for the pool to finish being created.**

Additionally, I suggest using:

1. Promises for your db functions, it will make you feel better about javascript ;D.
2. I suggest you use parameterized query functions. They help keep the
   code clean and also prevent you needing to deal with variable types
   / heavy escaping.
3. (BTW, I would put this in another file and export the parameterizedPromise via `exports.parameterizedPromise = parameterizedPromise.`

Here is a sample of how to use a parameterized query promise:
/*

```
parameterizedPromise('SELECT * FROM foodtable f WHERE f.flavor = $1 AND f.meal = $2;', ['SPICY', 'BREAKFAST'])
.then(function(result){
  console.log(result.rows);
})
.catch(function(error){
  console.warn(error);
});
*/
```

Here is a redacted version of what I had used a while back.

```
 const pg = require('pg');

  const DBConfig = {
      host: 'xxxxxx',
      port: 'xxxxxx',
      user: 'xxxxxx',
      password: 'xxxxxx',
      database: 'xxxxxx',
      max: 10,   // max number of clients in the pool
      ssl: true,
      idleTimeoutMillis: 30000  // how long a client is allowed to remain idle before being closed
  };

  const postgresPool = new pg.Pool(DBConfig, function(){
    console.log('connected to postgres database');

    // Need to wait for the pool to finish connecting before you can fire off your query.
    paramaterizedPromise(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS favoritememes (id serial PRIMARY KEY, image_url varchar(255), date_favorited TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);`, [])
    .then(function(result){
        console.log(result);
    })
    .catch(function(error){
        console.warn(error);
    });
  });


  postgresPool.on('error', function (err, client) {
    // if an error is encountered by a client while it sits idle in the pool
    // the pool itself will emit an error event with both the error and
    // the client which emitted the original error
    // this is a rare occurrence but can happen if there is a network partition
    // between your application and the database, the database restarts, etc.
    // and so you might want to handle it and at least log it out
    console.error('idle client error', err.message, err.stack);
  });



const paramaterizedPromise = function(query, params) {
  return new Promise( function(resolve, reject){
    postgresPool.connect(function(err, client, done) {
      if(err) {
        reject('Error Fetching Client From Pool', err);
      }
      client.query(query, params, function(err, result) {
        //call `done()` to release the client back to the pool
        done(err);
        if (err){
          reject(err);
        } else {
          resolve(result);
        }
      });
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: I also suggest that you promisify pg... but yeah. I think I already too too many liberties in adding on stuff in my answer.

Let me know if that works out for you or if you find something else that works better. I should probably return to some of my old apps and update the pg service some day... so any gems you figure out please share!